# How do I clear the selected value from a select box using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I don't want to remove the options, just clear the selected value.

I tried the following:

```
$("#myid").val("")
```

and that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `prop` method.

```
$("#myid option:selected").prop("selected", false)
```

Answer (score 1):

That'll only work if you have an option with an *empty* value:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

***HTML CODE***

```
<select id="myid">
    <option value="">Select None</option>
    <option value="0" id="item1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="1" id="item1">Item 2</option>
    <option value="2" id="item2">Item 3</option>
    <option value="3" id="item3">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myid').change(function(){
        var getVal= $('#myid').select().attr('value');
$('option[id=item'+getVal+']').attr('value','');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RtvPz/63/

Comment: @MFer is the code working? please inform me if modification needed.

Comment: @AKWF please have a close look to my answer. It might be helpful to you. Thanks